# Value from DropDownList will not save into SQL Server table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a DropDownList that gets populated by a SQL Server table called `tblVisa`. My issue is that the values that are being populated from the SQL Server table are not being saved. Everything else gets saved except for my DropDownLists. I've tried using `.SelectedValue` and `.Text`, but it still does not work.

Here is my code

```
protected void PopulateVisaType()
{
        List<ListItem> result = new List<ListItem> { new ListItem("", "") };

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand() { Connection = sqlConn, CommandText = "SELECT VisaType FROM tblVisa ORDER BY VisaType ASC" };

        if (sqlConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) 
        {
            sqlConn.Open(); 
        }

        SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (read.Read())
        {
            result.Add(new ListItem(read["VisaType"].ToString(), read["VisaType"].ToString()));
        }

        read.Close();
        sqlConn.Close();
        cmd.Dispose();

        DDLVisa.DataSource = result;
        DDLVisa.DataValueField = "value";
        DDLVisa.DataTextField = "text";
        DDLVisa.DataBind();
}
```

Here's my code for saving the information into the database:

```
protected void LbSaveProfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand() { Connection = sqlConn, CommandText = "spSaveNewProviderInformation", CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };

    if (sqlConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    { 
        sqlConn.Open(); 
    }

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeNumber", TbEmployeeNumber.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SSN", TbSSN.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContractType", DDLContractType.SelectedItem.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", TbFirstname.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lastname", TbLastname.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleInitial", TbMiddleInitial.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContractRenewalDate", TbContractRenewalDate.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Position", DDLPosition.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Specialty", DDLSpecialty.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrimaryDepartment", DDLPrimaryDepartment.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecondaryDepartment", DDLSecondaryDepartment.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", DDLGender.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Birthdate", TbBirthdate.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", TbEmailAddress.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", TbPhoneNumber.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", TbAddress.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PassportNumber", TbPassportNumber.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Citizenship", DDLCitizenship.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Visa", DDLVisa.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", 1);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    sqlConn.Close();

    Alert("Provider Information saved!");

    ClearControls();
}
```

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Did you debug your code? What value do you get in `DDLVisa.Text` and other DDL text?

Comment: Try `(ListItem)DDLVisa.SelectedValue`. Side note: you need `using` blocks on your connection, command and reader. Do *not* cache the connection

Comment: @Chetan Yes I added a breakpoint to help me trace the code. For all my DDL text, they were empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

You much better to provide the drop down list with column names.

So, say this:

```
    protected void PopulateVisaType()
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("");

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT VisaType FROM tblVisa ORDER BY VisaType ASC", sqlConn))
        {
            if (sqlConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                sqlConn.Open();
            }

            DDLVisa.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DDLVisa.DataValueField = "VisaType";
            DDLVisa.DataTextField = "VisaType";

            DDLVisa.DataBind();
            //DDLVisa.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(""));   // optional blank row choice

            sqlConn.Close();
        }
    }
```

So the TextField, and the DataText field need to be a named column from the data source.

I also included an optional first blank option if you need/want/expect to have no choice.

However, keep in mind that this empty string should be translated into a null in your database if you don't allow (or want) empty strings, and want a null for that value. This applies to all of your values. (perhaps the stored procedure does this?).